# C# to vb.net conversion

Tags: vb.net

I need to convert this code from C# to VB. I'm not sure of the proper syntax.

C#

```
[XcoWorkerExtension(Optional = new Type[] { typeof(Subscribe<OnNewsArrived>) })]
    private readonly XcoPublisher<OnNewsArrived> publisher = new    XcoPublisher<OnNewsArrived>();
```

This is what I've come up with in VB:

```
<XcoWorkerExtension([Optional]:=New Type() {GetType(Subscribe(Of OnNewsArrived))})> _
    Private ReadOnly publisher As New XcoPublisher(Of OnNewsArrived)()
```

The C# version runs fine but when I try to run the VB version I'm getting this exception:

System.IO.FileLoadException was unhandled
  Message=The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
  Source=mscorlib

The exception is generated at the first line of this sub:

```
internal XcoWorkerExtensionAttribute Get_worker_extension_attribute(FieldInfo field)
    {
        object[] fieldAttrs = field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XcoWorkerExtensionAttribute), false);
        object[] classAttrs = field.FieldType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XcoWorkerExtensionAttribute), false);
        if (fieldAttrs.Length > 0 && classAttrs.Length == 0)
            throw new XcoWorkerException("A field can only be marked with the XcoWorkerExtension attribute when its type is also marked with this attribute");

        if (fieldAttrs.Length > 0)
            return (XcoWorkerExtensionAttribute)fieldAttrs[0];
        if (classAttrs.Length > 0)
            return (XcoWorkerExtensionAttribute)classAttrs[0];
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for giving a "meta answer".

For small conversions like this, [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) is a nice tool if you are unsure about syntax and/or results.

Possibilities of use:

1. Compile in C#, and decompile to VB.Net.
2. Compile in VB.Net, compare to original

Comment: Ok well I guess I've eliminated synatx as the cause of the error.  I used Reflector and came up the same exact code.

Answer (score 0):

[C# to VB Converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)

Worked for one of my projects, though I suspect there are a few things that will make it unhappy. And you as well.

Comment: I assume he already tried this, seeing as how it generates the same VB.NET code he's using.

Comment: I tried this converter and another as well and both came up with the same results.

Comment: Fair enough, I hadn't tried plugging in your code. Have you done standard stuff like making sure the VB project has the same references, uses the same version of .NET, etc?

Comment: I created another project from scratch to make sure it wasn't something like that and had the same results.  I noticed that I can run the project fine if I remove the attribute from the Publisher deceleration.